# Samba, FreeBSD, ZFS: Group permissions are ignored

Tags: freebsd, zfs, access-control-list, samba4

I am running Samba 4.6 on FreeBSD 11 with ZFS. Each user belongs to the **fileserver group**. In addition, there are additional groups for each department, such as **sales group**.

And here comes my problem. On the server is a folder called **sales**. Which is owned by fileserver and the group sales. Why can't my group members from sales overwrite files via Windows inside this folder. Using a shell access the editing works without any problems.

Under Windows appears the message **Access to the destination folder has been denied** when I try to overwrite a file. New files can be created inside the sales folder without a problem. Renaming also works

```
folder sales
chmod 770 sales
chown fileserver:sales

# file: sales
# owner: fileserver
# group: sales
owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow
group@:rwxp--a-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

Inside the sales folder is a file **test.txt**

```
chmod 770 test.txt
chown fileserver:sales

# file: test.txt
# owner: fileserver
# group: sales
owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow
group@:rwxp--a-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

Changing the folder permissin to chmod 2770 sales has also no effect

Only if I give the file the same ACL rights as the owner the saving works. Why is that? Did I make a wrong setting? The group permission rights **rwx** should overule the ACL rights? No?

```
smb4.conf
[global]
# Logging
log level = 3
log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
max log size = 50
utmp = 0

# Domain & controller & workgroups
server string = NAS Server
workgroup = COMPANY
server string = NAS
netbios name = NAS

# Network restriction
bind interfaces only = yes
interfaces = lo0 igb0

# Security model
security = user
encrypt passwords = true
map to guest = bad user

# Time server
time server = yes

map hidden = no
map system = no
map archive = no
map readonly = no

store dos attributes = yes

ea support = yes
access based share enum = yes
load printers = no

template homedir = /fileserver/users/%U
allow insecure wide links = yes

[data]
comment = Data
path = /fileserver/data
valid users = +fileserver

browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
public = no
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes

create mask = 0770
force create mode = 0760
directory mask = 2770
force directory mode = 2770

hide unreadable = yes

vfs objects = shadow_copy2 zfsacl recycle crossrename
shadow: snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
shadow: sort = desc
shadow: format = %Y-%m-%d-%H%M

recycle:directory_mode = 0750
recycle:subdir_mode = 0750
recycle:exclude = *.tmp *.temp *.swp
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:repository = Trash/%U
recycle:versions = yes
recycle:touch = yes
recycle:touch_mtime = yes

nfs4:mode = special
nfs4:acedup = merge
nfs4:chown = yes

crossrename:sizelimit = 50
```

Comment: Please post the output of `zfs get all <dataset>` (replacing `dataset` with the correct ZFS filesystem).

Comment: zroot/fileserver aclmode passthrough local zroot/fileserver aclinherit passthrough local

Answer (score 0):

So, you expect the read-write access to work without `delete`, `delete_child` and `write_owner` ? This is just wrong, you are not inside the legacy 3x3 POSIX permissions system, it's NFSv4 ACLs. They aren't *additional* to POSIX 3x3, they are normalized. Basically you need the `full_set` ACL, in you need more fine-grained control you need to experiment.

And don't forget that you alsi need the `aclmode` and `aclinherit` set to `passthrough` on this dataset.

Comment: zroot/fileserver  aclmode               passthrough            local
zroot/fileserver  aclinherit              passthrough            local

Comment: As I mentioned above it works when I give the file the same rights as the owner which is rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow. There is only a write_owner permission not delete permission.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it’s not enough, and “works” cover a wide range of states as it’s very illusional verb: on one of it’s range of senses us a total failure, on the other - ultimately working solution. You probably need to start to read what you’re answered with.